# Make SQL Server on Azure server available locally

Tags: sql-server, azure, remote-connection

I have a Azure VM running, on which I have installed SQL Server.
But I cannot to SQL from SSMS on my local machine.

The server have a public IP and Remote Connections have been enabled, as well as TCP/IP protocols.
I have also checked that port 1433 is open on the firewall.
I've also created a Network Security Group on the VM as per screenshot below.

Anything else that might cause the problem (specific to Azure VM's)?

**Error:**

[image]

**NSG:**
[image]

**Firewall:**
[image]

Comment: can you add screenshots of the NSGs (if any), the windows firewall, and the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the necessary firewall configuration?

Alternatively you could create a [point to site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) or [site to site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create) VPN to allow the connection.

Comment: Yes, firewall has been configured, unless I've missed something. I just feel Azure must have the capability to make it available without the use of VPN's.

Comment: Did you give your VM an external IP address? Have you checked your Network Security Group endpoint rules? Can you RDP to it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to connect over named pipes. You should have enabled TCP/IP protocol locally on your machine and the Azure VM as well. By default, when you install SQL Server, the TCP/IP protocol is disabled.

To enable it you can use Sql Server Configuration Manager (or access it from Computer Management).

On your local machine: SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Native Client *xx* Configuration > Client Protocols. (This is for 64-bit client. SQL Native Client (32-bit) is for 32-bit client.)

On the server (Azure VM): SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for *MSSQLSSERVER*. Don't forget to restart the SQL Server instance once you enable the TCP/IP protocol on the server.